# AngularJS and base tag subfolder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to load all my static files from a version folder using the base tag like:

```
<base href="/build/123/">
```

I'm using this in my module config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
})
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
/build
  /123/
    /js/main.js
    /img/img1.jpg
index.html
```

All the files are loaded ok from the correct path but I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

on the line where I'm calling angular.bootstrap:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule']);
});
```

This doesn't happen if I use the files outside of the build folder and the base tag like:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem (i.e. all of your relevant code; maybe a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) example)?  It's a little unclear to me where Bootstrap sits in your project directory; maybe that's part of the problem.

Comment: @alex sorry for the late reply .... there's no Bootstrap in the project. I'm just calling angular.bootstrap which is a method you can use instead of ng-app directive.

Comment: Well *that's* embarassing - I'm a little new to AngularJS and I'm unfamiliar with the `angular.bootstrap()` function.  Nevertheless, I think that maybe something is being loaded incorrectly.  I'd imagine that you'd get that message if `angular` is undefined when it tries to call `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule']`.  You should consider recreating the issue in Plunker or JSFiddle.